# Unable to ping other boxes in Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created three instances of Riak in EC2. I am unable to ping these instance from one another. I don't see any response. How can I make them listen and reply back? I tried the following :

1. `ping ec2-35-160-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`
2. ping address of machine (got it from `ifconfig`)

Both did not work.

Comment: Most likely you need to open access between those machines using Security Group.

Comment: I have already opened it i believe ...

Comment: Also a working or not working ping is not an indication of connectivity or lack thereof. Ping is using ICMP protocol which might not be enabled or allowed. Here's a related answer on how to check if certain ports respond: http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port

Comment: i think its with security group only i have configured it though but not sure if its the right way. Is there a way i can share screen with you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your security group:

1. Go to "Instances" on the left side menu
2. click to launch-wizard-x under " Security Group " tab. ( x would be any digit number according to your VM)
3. then you have to edit Inbound rules by right-clicking on it.
4. you can add rules according to your requirements . I have added "All Traffic" but you have to enable only those rules that are required only.

Please refer to this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=22640

Comment: I have added all ports needed for communication in security group. Still no go. Any suggestion ?